# what is the meaning of "squat spitting"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> He grumbles a little about his possible eminence; the cardinal loves
>   his country, its May garlands, its tender birdsong. In his nightmares
>   he sees **squat spitting** Italians, a forest of nooses, a corpse-strewn
>   plain.
>
> — Wolf Hall by Hilary Mante

What is the meaning of "**squat spitting**"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it means "squat, spitting Italians"— that is, Italians who are squat ([short](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/squat#Adjective)), and who are also spitting.